# Performance of Map vs Optional in Java

Tags: java

I have a doubt about the performance difference between these two things, get an object directly from a hashmap with the key vs get it from an Optional from an ArrayList. I will use these to save big amounts of data.

Note: the example below is only to show what I mean; I don't use static except in utils or specific things, I say this to prevent comments about static.

```
public class Main {

    private static final List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User(UUID.randomUUID()), new User(UUID.randomUUID()), new User(UUID.randomUUID()));

    public static Optional<User> getUserByUUID(final UUID uuid){
        return users.stream().filter(user -> user.getUuid().equals(uuid)).findFirst();
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Getter@Setter
    private static class User{
        private final UUID uuid;
        private int points;
        private int gems;
    }

}
```

vs

```
public class Main {

    private static final Map<UUID, User> users = new HashMap<UUID, User>(){{
        put(UUID.randomUUID(), new User());
        put(UUID.randomUUID(), new User());
    }};
            

    public static User getUserByUUID(final UUID uuid){
        if(users.containsKey(uuid))
            return users.get(uuid);
        return null;
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Getter@Setter
    private static class User{
        private int points;
        private int gems;
    }

}
```

My point is, if one is better than the another one in terms of performance, is it insignificant?

Comment: You can simplify your code in the map version to `return users.get(uuid);`. Checking for `containsKey` and then using `get` **doubles** the cost, where just using `get` suffices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Map#get` will always be more performant than creating a `Stream` from a `List` and looking for a specific entry.

`Map#get` will give you a time complexity of `O(1)` basically

`List#stream` instead will give you a time complexity of `O(n)` plus extra space complexity: creation of a `Stream` and creation of an `Optional`

---

That said, if you have *big amounts of data* loaded in memory, this might lead to performance problems / `OutOfMemoryError`s

It would be interesting to dig further in the problem and see if there isn't another way to handle this specific problem without loading *big amounts of data* directly in memory of the JVM

Comment: I'm saving and loding data into SQLite or MySQL, so i have no way to save memory in another place since it's a plugin, and my question was  because i won't have just one HashMap or just one Arrays, I need a few for what I have in mind

Comment: @R3bck ok if your process is backed by a database, that's already great. Don't hesitate to benchmark your process too.

Comment: Yes i'm using hikari for a pool , and i already knew about the O(1) and O(n) but my point was if the answer if the same for big amount of data and multiple arrays or maps, i use SQLLite or MySQL just for load data and save data when the plugin ends, also i save data async while plugin is running

Comment: Yes the answer remains the same anyway @R3bck, the second part is just an extra

Comment: @R3bck If you're using a database, then _let the database do its job_ and make a SQL query instead of keeping your own in-memory copy.

Comment: @chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic- that'd be soooo bad for what i'm doing